# ReferenceError: describe is not defined WHEN run npm run dev

Tags: javascript, express, npm

Any something wrong with my package.json? The test is green when I run npm run test. But when I run npm run dev, the test is also run. There is no command config I write that it should run test when I run npm run dev

[image: project structure]

here is my package.json

```
  "name": "domundotech-cashier",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "set DEBUG=domundotech-cashier:* & nodemon --exec & npm start",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha \"*/*.spec.js\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acorn": "^8.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^24.3.3",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "express-useragent": "^1.0.15",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "node-device-detector": "^1.3.4",
    "npm": "^7.8.0",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.6.2",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-test-helpers": "^1.3.2",
    "proxyquire": "^2.1.3",
    "mocha": "^8.3.2",
    "chai": "^4.3.4",
    "sinon": "^10.0.0",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.6.0",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.20.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.20.0",
    "eslint": "^7.23.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.3.1",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"
  }
}
```

and this for the error logs
[image: error logs]

Comment: The problem isn't in your package.json, the error log says in Absent.spec.js on line 7, the function `describe` is not defined. Trace where the `describe` function was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Describe is defined in my test file. For now, I found the solution that I should ignore (-i) test files when executing nodemon :)

```
    "start": "node ./bin/www",
    "dev": "set DEBUG=domundotech-cashier:* & nodemon -i ./test & npm start",
    "test": "mocha \"./test/*/*.spec.js\""
  },
```

And I refactor my project structure too